# smart micro Radar ROS node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with smart micro radars type 29,30 and 31. Has anyone implemented ROS node for this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258395/smart-micro-radar-ros-node/) by [Wallizada](https://answers.ros.org/users/29895/wallizada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-04-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-01**:
You question would be more clear if you had a link to the product. Are you referring to these: http://www.smartmicro.de/automotive-radar/products/ ?

**Comment by [Wallizada](https://answers.ros.org/users/29895/wallizada/) on 2017-04-01**:
Thanks, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They have a ROS1 driver available themselves in the downloads section: https://www.smartmicro.com/downloads

And a ROS2 version is available here: https://github.com/smartmicro/smartmicro_ros2_radars

---

Originally posted by [Timple86](https://answers.ros.org/users/22432/timple86/) with karma: 80 on 2022-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0